# Seeking laymans explaination of the pending intent concept

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

This is a pretty stale question but frankly I'm yet to find it answered in a way that satisfies my curiosity.

Before you, dear reader, leap to the android developer reference to paste me the text, please be aware that I've already read the Intent / Pending Intent documentation and am yet to resolve my confusion.

It strikes me that the Intent model is core to the android system and as such is highly generic. It is because of this that the examples I have seen of its usage tend to be many and varied. This variation obfuscates the concepts I am trying to learn and that is frustrating.

My questions are simply written but perhaps tough to explain in simple terms. I understand that an intent is a message to other activities and that other activities can declare their interest in their manifest. Pending intent, a wrapper for intent, confuses me.

1. I see documentation referring to permissions and token. I get that, but why is pending intent needed as a separate entity - what behavior does it enable?
2. What activity / task lifecycle behaviour do pending intents cause?
3. When is a broadcast receiver required?
4. What are a broadcast receiver's limitations?

I realise these are seriously newb questions (which I am) but I desperately want to understand these core concepts so I don't have to rely on example / guides / official docs as much.

Any feedback is welcome folks. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main purpose of a PendingIntent is to give another application written permission to do something in your stead. Applications are restricted in what they are allowed to do by, essentially, these two factors:

- Visibility. Components like Services or Activities that aren't provided with a publicly visible (or any) intent-filter cannot be called by other applications. They can only be called by your application using explicit intents specifying their package and class name.
- Permissions. Each application can request a certain amount of permissions. Those are mostly predefined permissions, but you do have the option to define your own permissions as well, though I never used that. Your application cannot do anything that exceeds those permissions.

Now, with pending intents, you can get past both of those restrictions, if an application that *has* the required permissions and visibility to do something specifically allows *you* to do it in her stead. An application could allow you to call one of her private Activities for example, if it gives you a pending intent that contains an explicit intent for said activities.

[edit]
They are used with the alarm manager, for example. It tells the alarm manager what and when to do by giving it a (pending) intent. Since your application probably won't be there any more when the time arrives, the alarm manager will have to send it for you. That would mean that those intents could only do what the alarm manager is allowed to do, not what your application is allowed to do. If the alarm manager was allowed to simply do anything, every application could do anything by using the alarm manager as a proxy. So you have to use pending intents to specifically grant the alarm manager the rights it needs for your particular intent.[/edit]

Apart from that, there isn't too much of a difference to regular intents, at least as far as usage is concerned. It does get a bit more complicated with sticky intents etc, but that's the general gist of it, at least as far as I know.

A broadcast receiver is required when you want to react to certain [system events](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html), or events of other applications. A broadcast receiver is invisible, it doesn't create any form of view and doesn't involve any form of user interaction. The advantage is that this can happen irregardless of whether your application (or rather, your activities) are currently running or not.

A broadcast receiver is only granted about 10 seconds to do stuff, after that it gets killed by the system. So if you want to perform any kind of long running processes you'll have to use a background service, or open up an Activity to let your users do stuff.

Comment: Excellent write-up. I feel much more confident with this concept now. Thank you for the quick answer.